# Meteor on finish renderlist

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to get a callback for when an entire list renders?

I've tried

```
Template.articles.rendered = function() {
  var lastChapter = Chapters.findOne({}, {
    sort: {
      createdTime: -1
    }
  })

  if (lastChapter._id != this.data._id)
    return

  doSomething()

};
```

But this is unreliable because chapters are added 1 by 1 instead of all at once, so this actually fires multiple times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`rendered` is called when a part of the template is re-rendered, so you should check inside your rendered method whether you want to do anything now. When does "the entire list renders" happen? You know that in your code, for instance by checking if the list is of an expected length yet.

Comment: How do you know what the expected length is (length is variable depending on the user)?

Comment: I guess that depends - if you know how many items you're planning on drawing, then you can just count back from that to 0 and then you'll know.